# After obtaining more data the open panel is not correct

Tags: vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

When loading the panels the first time and opening the panel in the third position. Everything is Ok.
[image: When loading the panels the first time and opening the panel in the third position. All is Ok.]

When loading more elements, the panel that opens is not correct but it is still the one in the third position.
[image: When loading more elements, the panel that opens is not correct but it is still the one in the third position.]

```
<div id="load-conversation">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" v-show="referencesList.length >0">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button  v-on:click="getEmails" class="btn btn-sm btn-blue">Cargar más</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-info" v-for="email in emails">
        <!-- Head Panel-->
        <div class="panel-heading" v-bind:class=" email.incoming ? 'white-inbox' : 'blue-reply'" 
                                   data-toggle="collapse" :href="`#collapse-new${email.id}`">
            <!--Email Title-Button -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h5 v-if="email.incoming"><span class="fas fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></span> ${email.sender_name}</h5>
                    <h5 v-else><span class="fas fa-share-square" aria-hidden="true"></span> ${email.sender_name}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Body Panel-->
        <div :id="`collapse-new${email.id}`" class="panel-collapse collapse">

            <div class="panel-body">
                <!--Email Head-->
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">

                            <strong>SUBJECT: </strong><span class="text-info">${email.subject}</span></br>
                            <strong>FROM: </strong><span class="text-info">${email.sender_email}</span></br>
                            <strong>TO: </strong><span class="text-info"><span v-for="to in email.to">${to.email}, </span></span></br>
                            <strong>DATE: </strong><span class="text-info">${email.date}</span></br>
                            <strong v-if="email.cc.length > 0">CC: </strong><span class="text-info"><span v-for="cc in email.cc">${cc.email}, </span></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <!--Email Body-->
                <div class="row container-fluid">
                    <div class="list-group-item"v-html="email.content_html">



                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="bs-component">
                            <ul class="pager">
                                <li class="previous" data-toggle="collapse" :data-target="`#open-details-new${email.id}`">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div :id="`open-details-new${email.id}`" class="collapse" v-html="email.complete_html">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The important thing is to see that the new elements are placed in the order of the old elements, that is, the order is reversed in the list. By only adding the elements without changing the order everything works correctly.

```
<script>

    var loadMore = new Vue({
        el: '#load-conversation',
        delimiters: ['${', '}'],
        data: {
            limit    : 3,
            referencesList : [1,2,3,4,5],
            emails : [],
            showLoadBtn: true,
        },
        mounted() { 
            this.getEmails()
        },
        methods: {
            getEmails(){
                axios.post("get_more_emails", { references: this.getReferences() })
                .then(response => {
                    //console.log(response.data);
                    this.emails = [ ...response.data, ...this.emails ]
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('error', error)
                });

            },
            getReferences(){
               ...
            }
        },
    })
</script>
```